# Generic insertion sort

Tags: c, sorting, reinventing-the-wheel, insertion-sort, c99

I implemented a generic insertion sort routine that can sort an array of any type. It's similar to the qsort function from the standard library. My goal it to optimize the code for readability above everything else, so I would appreciate any feedback.

```
void isort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size, int (*compar)(const void *, const void *)) {
    for (size_t i = 1; i < nmemb; i++) {
        char *key = (char *)base + i * size;
        char key_copy[size];
        memcpy(key_copy, key, size);

        char *curr = NULL;
        for (curr = key; curr > base && compar(curr - size, key_copy) > 0; curr -= size) {
            memcpy(curr, curr - size, size);
        }

        memcpy(curr, key_copy, size);
    }
}
```

Example client code:

```
int cmp_int(const void *p, const void *q) {
    return *(int *)p - *(int *)q;
}

int main(void) {
    int arr[] = { 4, 2, 3, 0, 2, 5 };
    size_t nelem = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    isort(arr, nelem, sizeof(arr[0]), cmp_int);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < nelem; i++) {
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Please tell us the version of standard C that you are using, some features you are using are not available in a versions.

Comment: I'm using ISO C99

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Too many calls to memcpy. You don't need to `memcpy` individual elements. Once you found the place where `key_copy` should land, `memmov`e the entire block of elements in one go.
- A mandatory *no naked loops* mantra.

  Every loop implements and algorithm, and therefore deserves a name. Make the inner loop a function.
- A mandatory insertion sort review.

  This implementation is suboptimal. At every iteration of an inner loop *two* conditions are tested: `curr > base` &and `compar(curr - size, key_copy) > 0`. You may get away with only one test per iteration (and perhaps less calls to `compar`).

  Compare the current key with the base key. If it is less, you know it shall land at the base; don't bother to compare anymore - just shift the entire block to the right. Otherwise, the base key serves as a natural sentinel, and you never hit a `curr == base` case.

All that said, consider

```
void isort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size, int (*compar)(const void *, const void *)) {
    for (size_t i = 1; i < nmemb; i++) {
        char * curr = (char *)base + i * size;
        char * insertion_point = base;

        if (compar(base, curr) <= 0) {
            insertion_point = find_insertion_point_unguarded(base, curr, compar, size);
        }

        char key_copy[size];
        memcpy(key_copy, curr, size);
        memmove(insertion_point + size, insertion_point, curr - insertion_point);
        memcpy(insertion_point, key_copy, size);
    }
}
```

An implementation of `find_insertion_point_unguarded` left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Amazing! This is exactly the kind of feedback I was looking for. Thank you very much!